# C++, threads, and pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, c++11

I am using std::thread to execute multiple threads.  I pass a pointer to an array as an argument, something akin to:

```
my_type* rest[count];
//Fill rest array
std::thread(fnc, rest, count);
```

The issue I seem to be having, is that somewhere along the way, the pointer values in 'rest' get corrupted.  I print out the pointer values before the call to std::thread, and first thing in the function that std::thread calls on my behalf, and the values do not match.  It seems fairly random, sometimes they will match, and sometimes not (and a segfault results when the latter happens).

I know (from what little I could find on the topic) that std::thread copies the arguments, and I am thinking that my issue stems from this, and that there is a special function std::ref() that allows it to pass references, but none of them mention pointers specifically.  I have tried various techniques to attempt to pass this array with std::ref() but I have yet to solve the issue.

Am I correct in thinking that this could be the cause of my issue, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Is `rest` a local variable, by any chance? Does it maybe go out of scope before `fnc` starts executing? `std::thread` will just copy the pointer to the first element of the array - but not elements themselves. They better stay alive for as long as `fnc` is running.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No rest is a pointer that should never go out of scope.  Its passed in to my "create thread" function, and is valid before the std::thread call, and valid after it. The actual pointer (printed by %p with printf) is different inside of the new thread.  Now when I put a sleep(1) after the thread creation (allowing the thread to complete before the calling function does) it (appears) to work.  I have been trying to find any reason that it could happen, since 'rest' lives long past the function.

Comment: "and is valid before the std::thread call, and valid after it" Is it valid for the entire life of the thread though? When you pass an array in C++ it gets automatically converted to a pointer (unfortunately, a bad behavior inherited from C), so if the array is a local variable then you're passing a pointer to a local variable; the local variable must remain alive for as long as that pointer is used.

Comment: Because of the bad behavior of raw arrays in C++ I recommend you either use `std::array` or `std::vector`. Both have value semantics, which are much more sensible than the weirdness of raw arrays.

Comment: @bames53 Each item in the array should be valid, since its an array of pointers that have a very long life, but the array itself is created as shown above, if gets converted in some fashion (the array pointer, not the contents) then I would have a problem.  Is there a way to suppress this behavior?  I would rather not use a container class if at all possible.

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Your sample code creates a temporary thread that's just going to be destroyed while joinable, which will lead to std::terminate. Can you provide a working example? And if that's working, your implementation probably should be broken.

Comment: @chico I am fairly certain that bames53 hit the nail on the head.  Knowing the layout of my code, his explanation makes perfect sense.  If it turns out that it is not the case, I will return with a small code sample that hopefully demonstrates the behavior, although it is a little difficult to distill 10k lines of tightly integrated code into a simple test case, which is why I wanted to know if there was some simple concept I was missing before I took that step.  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Hi Latreides. I assume that your threads are all running same function only. Right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if gets converted in some fashion (the array pointer, not the contents) then I would have a problem.

Yes, that's exactly what happens.

It's often incorrectly said that arrays are just pointers. The truth of the matter is that whenever you declare a function that takes an array:

```
void foo(int x[10]);
```

The declaration is 'adjusted' so that the parameter is a pointer:

```
void foo(int *x); // C++ can't tell the difference between this and the first declaration
```

and when you call the function:

```
int x[10];
foo(x);
```

There's an implicit conversion equivalent to the following:

```
int x[10];

int *tmp = &x[0];

foo(tmp);
```

So what happens is that you have a block of memory containing your pointers to long lived objects:

```
my_type *rest[count] = {new my_type, new my_type, new my_type};
```

You pass a pointer to that block of memory to the thread:

```
thread(fnc, &rest[0], count);
```

Then when the function returns `rest` goes out of scope, and that block of memory is no longer valid.

Then the thread follows the pointer to the block of memory and reads garbage. If by some chance it does read the correct array contents then it can access the long lived objects just fine. The problem is getting the pointers to the long lived objects from the corrupt block of memory where `rest` used to be on the stack.

> Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

In most cases the only thing that makes sense is not use raw arrays as function parameters. You can wrap a raw array in a struct and get the sensible behavior:

```
struct int_array {
  int x[10];
};

void foo(int_array x);

int main() {
  int_array x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
  foo(x); // the array is copied rather than getting strangely converted
}
```

This is pretty much exactly what `std::array` does, so you're better off using it.

In cases where you don't want a copy of the array you can take a reference to the array:

```
int foo(int (&x)[10]);
```

This gives you essentially the same behavior as the weird 'adjustments' and implicit conversions that are done behind your back with `int foo(int x[10]); foo(x);`. The benefit here is that it's explicit and that you get type checking on the size of the array. That is, due to the 'adjustment' the following does not result in a compiler error:

```
int foo(int x[10]);

int x[3];
foo(x);
```

Whereas this will:

```
int foo(int (&x)[10]);

int x[3];
foo(x); // the implicit conversion to &x[0] does not get happen when the function takes a reference to array
```

Comment: This is likely the issue I am facing.  I was not aware that C++ did this under the hood and assumed that if I created an array in that fashion that it would live beyond the scope it was created in.  This was not an issue in my application before I started using multiple threads, so I never had occasion to witness it before.  Thank you for this helpful explanation.

Comment: While the solution to use std::vectors or std::lists does appear to solve my issue (all the test cases work without a single segfault yet), it does so at a huge performance hit.  Large operations that before took ~1100 ms to complete, now take ~13400 to complete with std::list, and this is even more pronounced with std::vector.  I have yet to try std::array because it does not appear that I can pass any size of an std::array to a function since it takes its size through the template.

Comment: I'd have to see details of the program to know the best solution. For example solutions could be moving vectors instead of copying or going back to an array but with an appropriate lifetime.

Comment: The lifetime of the array is an unknown factor. I do not copy the vector (at least to my knowledge) as I pass pointers to the vector as it walks through my functions.  Granted I am not sure what little tricks C/C++ is doing under the hood.  I am working on solving it with the struct trick, in hopes that it will be more on par with the original speeds.

Comment: I tried your struct trick @bames53 and while it is much faster than vectors, it is still about almost 3x slower (~1100 to ~2780)  than it was with the 'pure' array.  Do you know of any reason why this would be the case?  I know that it may very well be dependent on any number of factors that are specific to my application, but if there are any 'known' penalties for passing/accessing struct pointers to an array vs an array directly, it would help me profile the problem.

Comment: Actually, I managed to keep using the array pointers in 99% of my application and only use the struct trick in the new thread creation function, so I do not pay any penalties except in those rare instances when a new thread is created.  Thank you very much for your help in understanding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you be aware of the risk of your code, try execute this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void f() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    {
        auto t = std::thread(f);
        std::cout << "0" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(400));
    std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
}
```

You'll see `2` and `3` never get to output, because the application is aways terminated.

In truth, it's more subtle, since at my sample, I've moved the thread to `t`. Resembling your original sample and not assigning the thread to any variable, there's no early termination, but `"hello"` never gets to output. (probably there was an optimization to eliminate the temporary, since it's never used; it just got destroyed before getting joinable; or who knows...)